# Can $A\sin^2t + B\sin t\cos t + C\sin t + D\cos t + E = 0$ be solved algebraically?

Tags: trigonometry

This started out much more complex, but I've reduced an equation to this (it's for finding intersections of ellipses):

$$A\sin^2(t)+B\sin(t)\cos(t)+C\sin (t)+D\cos(t)+E=0$$

I want to solve for t where A/B/C/D/E are constants.  Is this solvable algebraically, or is only numeric approximation possible?

Using trig identities and the formula for phase shifting, I can further simplify it down to this form:

$$\sin(2t+F) + G\sin(t+H) = I$$

Where F/G/H/I are constants.  The formula is much simpler, but this may be a dead end, because now we have two angles to deal with.

Comment: you can express all functions $\sin(t),\cos(t)$ in $$\tan(t/2)$$

Comment: you will get a polynomial of degree four

Comment: So using the identity sin(t) = +/- tan(t) / sqrt(1 + tan^2(t)) ?

Comment: Reduce to the pair of equations $Ax^2 + Bxy+ Cx+Dy +E = 0, x^2+y^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes use $$\sin(t)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( t/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( t/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
$$\cos(t)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( t/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( t/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and after this you can substitute $$\tan(t/2)=z$$

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a degree four equation. Set $X=\cos t$ and $Y=\sin t$, so you get
$$
\begin{cases}
AY^2+BXY+CY+DX+E=0\\[4px]
X^2+Y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
therefore the intersection of a hyperbola with a circle.

If you substitute $Y^2=1-X^2$ in the first equation, you get $A(1-X^2)+BXY+CY+DX+E=0$ and, solving for $Y$,
$$
Y=\frac{AX^2-DX-A-E}{BX+C}
$$

Substituting this in $X^2+Y^2=1$ yields the quartic:
$$
X^2(BX+C)^2+(AX^2-DX-A-E)^2=(BX+C)^2
$$
Note that the coefficient of $X^4$ is $A^2+B^2$, which is not zero unless $A=B=0$, when the equation becomes much simpler.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't understand your first substitution (starting with "Y=").  The final substitution obviously follows from the first, but could you hint what's being substituted for what?  Maybe another step or two would make it more obvious.

Comment: @BryceWagner Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Not sure why I had such a hard time seeing that.

Comment: @BryceWagner Oh, don't worry; I think it's better explained now.